How to get records which meet conditions stored in another tables
Problem: How to get passed requirements where there are 4 tables in such relation
requirements->links<-test_cases    test_cases->results<-result
Scenario:
Table1 - requirements



req_id
status




req-1
open


req-2
open



Table2 - test_cases



test_id
status




tc-1
open


tc-2
cancelled



Table3 - links



link_id
req_id
test_id




link-1
req-1
tc-1


link-2
req-1
tc-2



Table4 - test results



result_id
test_id
result




res-1
tc-1
passed


res-2
tc-2
failed



So far I've tried such an approach to generate a table
req_id | cnt_test_cases | cnt_results
and treat requirement as passed when cnt_test_cases = cnt_results(='passed')
but it doesn't work as these calculated columns doesn't exist for 'Having' statement at the end
SELECT DISTINCT requirements.req_id,

(SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT test_cases.test_id)
FROM test_cases, links
WHERE links.req_id = requirements.req_id
AND links.test_id = test_cases.test_id
AND test_cases.status != 'cancelled') as cnt_test_cases,

(SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT results.result)
FROM results, links
WHERE links.req_id = requirements.req_id
AND links.test_id = results.test_id
AND results.reuslt = 'passed') as cnt_test_cases) as cnt_results

Having cnt_test_cases = cnt_results
Maybe there is a better approach?

Which database system?

One solution would be to wrap the SELECT you already have into yet another SELECT and then filter the differences in the outer select using WHERE clause.
Something like this:
SELECT *
FROM 
  (
    SELECT
      requirements.req_id,
      (
        SELECT 
          COUNT (DISTINCT test_cases.test_id) 
        FROM test_cases, links 
        WHERE links.req_id = requirements.req_id 
            AND links.test_id = test_cases.test_id 
            AND test_cases.status != 'cancelled'
      ) as cnt_test_cases,
      (
        SELECT 
          /*
          This seems wrong. You likely don't want to 
          squash different 'passed' results into single number?
          */
          COUNT (DISTINCT results.result) 
        FROM results, links 
        WHERE links.req_id = requirements.req_id 
            AND links.test_id = results.test_id 
            AND results.result = 'passed'
      ) as cnt_results
     FROM dbo.requirements
  ) x
WHERE cnt_test_cases = cnt_results
  /* you might want to put in here something like 
    AND cnt_results > 0
  to make sure there are are at least some passed requirements
  */

Fiddle

Thank You. It works!

By running the following query we can find your recordset matrix
select r.[req_id], r.[status] req_status,
l.[link_id], l.[req_id] link_req_id, l.[test_id] link_test_id,
t.[test_id], t.[status] test_status,
s.[result_id], s.[test_id] result_test_id, s.[result] from [dbo].[requirements] r
left join [dbo].[links] l on r.req_id=l.req_id
left join [dbo].[test_cases] t on l.test_id=t.test_id
left join [dbo].[results] s on t.test_id=s.test_id

as shown in the picture

I think you are tring to find how many test cancelled and passed depend on the requirement. The query had some mistakes, I comment them.
SELECT DISTINCT requirements.req_id,
    
(SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT test_cases.test_id) 
FROM test_cases, links 
WHERE links.req_id = requirements.req_id AND 
links.test_id = test_cases.test_id AND 
test_cases.status != 'cancelled') as cnt_cancelled_test_cases,
--cnt_test_cases,
    
(SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT results.result) 
FROM results, links 
WHERE links.req_id = requirements.req_id AND 
links.test_id = results.test_id AND 
results.result = 'passed') as cnt_passed_test_cases
 --) as cnt_results
    
FROM requirements
--Having cnt_test_cases = cnt_results

The result is as follows


Thank You as well!
